# Bootstrap modal title form carousel

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap modal setup with a carousel inside. How do I get the carousel title to show in the modal `header-title` when I change the carousel item? Could someone help me with the JQuery?

This the code I have...

```
    <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12 isotope-item web-design-port">
     <div class="portfolio-container">
      <div class="portfolio-image">
       <img class="img-responsive" src="images/portfolio/portfolio-1.jpg">
         <div class="portfolio-overlayer"></div>
          <div class="portfolio-info">
           <div class="portfolio-title">Website Design</div>
           <div class="portfolio-category">Website</div>        
            <a title="TITLE FROM IMAGE" class="btn" href="#myModal1" data-toggle="modal" data-slide-to="2"></a>
          </div>
      </div>
     </div><
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one https://jsfiddle.net/renzuii/dpc7v436/

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12 isotope-item web-design-port">

<div class="portfolio-container">
    <div class="portfolio-image">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="images/portfolio/portfolio-1.jpg">
      <div class="portfolio-overlayer"></div>
      <div class="portfolio-info">
        <div class="portfolio-title">Website Design</div>
        <div class="portfolio-category">Website</div>        
        <a title="TITLE FROM IMAGE1" class="btn clicktomodal" href="#myModal1">Click to show modal</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal1" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="modaltitle"></h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('a.clicktomodal').on('click', function(e){

e.preventDefault();
  $('#modaltitle').text(this.title);

    $('#myModal1').modal('show')
})
```